# Indexes for select performance

Tags: mysql, select, index-tuning

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` enum('new','paid') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `can_be_closed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `close_reason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interval_before_close` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

And following select:

```
SELECT `id`, `status`, `close_reason` AS `closeReason`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` 
FROM `t1` as t
WHERE (
`t`.`status` = 'new' 
AND `t`.`updatedAt` < '2018-06-22 10:14:36' + INTERVAL `interval_before_close` MINUTE 
AND `t`.`can_be_closed` = true
)
```

For this query, explain return a full table scan.

I tried to add the following indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `t1` 
ADD INDEX `updatedAt` (`updatedAt` ASC);
```

and:

```
ALTER TABLE `t1` 
ADD INDEX `updatedAt` (`updatedAt` ASC, `interval_before_close` ASC);
```

but without any change in explain.

Fidle ex.: [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iwavoJbUQMn5bnDJYknabK/0)

Comment: I think that the index is not used cause you're selecting columns that are not included in the index, and a index seek + lookup is probably too expensive to do compared to a full table scan. Can you try to add to your index the columns `status` and `can_be_closed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Plan A (not good):**

Off hand, I would say it is optimal is to list `=` column(s) first, then a range:

```
INDEX(status, can_be_closed,   -- in either order
      updatedAt)               -- last
```

But...  It is more complicated than that.

```
'2018...' + INTERVAL interval_before_close ...
```

is essentially a function call to compute a date.  That makes it useless to put either `updatedAt` or `interval_before_close` in the index.

**Plan B (wimpy):**

So...  The following *may* be useful, but only if not many of the rows match those two flags:

```
INDEX(status, can_be_closed)   -- in either order
```

[*Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

**Plan C (complex):**

If, on the other hand, you had a column (real or computed) that contained

```
updatedAt - INTERVAL interval_before_close MINUTE
```

Say that it column is called `early_close`; then change to

```
AND early_close < '2018-06-22 10:14:36'
```

and add

```
INDEX(status, can_be_closed, early_close)
```